# Oracle SQL Use of Case When

Tags: sql, oracle, conditional-statements

I have a table like this:

```
Table a
ID   col1  col2 col3
1    'A'   123  234
2    'A'   222  333
2    'B'   223  334
```

Now, based on the contents in col1, I want to print the results in separate columns; for example, expected results are:

```
id ColA1 ColA2 ColB1 ColB2
1  123    234   na     na
2  222    333   223    334
```

But, when I do this:

```
select
id,
case when col1 = 'A' then col2 else 'na' end as colA1,
case when col1 = 'A' then col3 else 'na' end as colA2,
case when col1 = 'B' then col2 else 'na' end as colB1,
case when col1 = 'B' then col3 else 'na' end as colB2
from tableA
```

I receive this:

```
id ColA1 ColA2 ColB1 ColB2
1  123    234   na     na
2  222    333   na     na
2   na     na   223    334
```

I want the two rows for id=2 to be in one row.

How do I get the expected result?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want one row per ID, one approach is to group by the ID, applying an appropriate group function to each column expression.  MIN or MAX will work for the group function:

```
select
id,
NVL( MAX(case when col1 = 'A' then col2 else NULL end), 'na' ) as colA1,
NVL( MAX(case when col1 = 'A' then col3 else NULL end), 'na' ) as colA2,
NVL( MAX(case when col1 = 'B' then col2 else NULL end), 'na' ) as colB1,
NVL( MAX(case when col1 = 'B' then col3 else NULL end), 'na' ) as colB2
from tableA
group by id
```

You could also probably do this with the PIVOT feature.

Comment: Good answer, small corrections: aliases should be moved outside brackets otherwise I got `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`.
And if original query works that means that col2 and col3 are varchar, so `max()` has to be changed to `min()` or safer - 
construction nvl(max(case ... WITHOUT ELSE ... end), 'na'). Sorry for bothering ;-) And here is [pivot version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f3dc3/1).

Comment: don't you want to make the pivot version an answer?

Comment: @Mina  I wasn't aware of 'pivot'. I would love to know. Thank you.

Comment: @Mina - 1) no, Dave already mentioned pivot version as possibility, it's enough, this is very basic pivot query. In SQLfiddle I only showed correct syntax.
2) please address your comment to proper person (me in this case) by using _@ nickname_, I noticed your comment accidentally.

Comment: @PonderStibbons Thanks, fixed the mistake on the aliases.  Don't think I agree with your other point, though.  Regardless of the datatype, both MIN and MAX should prefer non-NULL values; they don't show the same behavior as ORDER BY.

Comment: If col2 or col3 are number type, we get 'ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes' with your [current](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/08754/1) query and OP's [original](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/08754/2) query. 
So I assumed that col2 and col3 are varchar. And values 'na' are greater then _123_, _234_ etc. So simply `max()` is not enough.

Comment: Your original answer about aggregating is OK, please add my pivot version to your answer if you want, it will be good enough. I don't like long discussion, English is not primary.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with pivot feature. below query displaying results as you expected.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT ID,COL1,COL2,COL3
FROM TABLEA)
PIVOT(SUM(COL2) C1,
SUM(COL3) C2
FOR COL1 IN('A','B') )
```